# Please add a feature to sort all tagged questions by the most favorited votes

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, tags

I would like to be able to see which question is the most favorite overall as well as in a specific tag.

Comment: I don't think 'favotites' should be a badge, I'll remove that.

Comment: I thought it's just a rudimentary grouping  of all questions in the database, and a UI tab. It just a guess -- I'm likely to be  wrong :)

Comment: +1 Good idea! Done something like this, somewhere else ;)

Answer (score 1):

On Stackoverflow:

1. [Hidden Features of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)
2. [What's your favorite programmer-related cartoon.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) (sadly)
3. [Programmer Jokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/programmer-jokes-whats-your-best-one)
4. [What should a developer know before building a public web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)
5. [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

I'm particularly fond of #4, but then I'm biased.