# How can I get a list of the most often bookmarked / "marked as Favorite" answers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, sorting

I wonder whether it's possible to sort the questions by meta-data: how often people mark a question as a "Favorite" within Stack Overflow or just the top-voted questions?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/please-add-a-feature-to-sort-all-tagged-questions-by-the-most-favorited-votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already sort the questions by votes. Just use the sorting tabs.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

As for the favorites, I am not sure how this would ever be valuable, but you could probably do it easily with a data dump query.